# Python script doesn't search for correct directory when using for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using for loops to search in many directories and pull out netcdf files to then plot. My current python script for looking through directories looks like this:

```
length = ['05','10','25','50'] 
time = ['06','12','24','48'] 
depth = ['100','200','500'] 
for length in length:
    for time in time:
        for depth in depth:

            nfdir = '/u/gens/nieto/stoch'
            ncfn=nfdir + '/stoch_' + length + 'km_' + time + 'h_' + depth + 'm_010T_002S_00U/ncom3d.nc'
```

The error I get is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/u/gens/nieto/stoch/stoch_05km_12h_5m_010T_002S_00U/ncom3d.nc'
```

It shortens the 500 in my list to 5 which there is no directory for because that isn't what I am testing. Not sure how to fix this given it seems like such a blatant error.

EDIT: Just wanted to note I'm relatively new to Python so excuse the bad taste in code.

Comment: Hmm, does `for depth in depth` seem like a bad idea?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name for the value and the iterable in your for loops.

Comment: @JaredGoguen even though its bad practice, that's not causing the issue

Comment: @JoeIddon Yes it is

Comment: @JaredGoguen It works fine for me when testing with a simpler case

Comment: @JoeIddon see my answer

Comment: @JaredGoguen Ah! Thanks for clearing it up, I missed that this would bound the last `element` to the `variable`. **:)**

Answer (score 2):

The for loops of `for depth in depth`, `for length in length` ..etc are causing the failures.

Changing them solves it.

```
lengths = ['05','10','25','50']   # <-- renamed length to lengths
times = ['06','12','24','48']  # <-- renamed time to times
depths = ['100','200','500']  # <-- renamed depth to depths
for length in lengths:  # <-- use lengths
    for time in times:  # <-- use times
        for depth in depths:  # <-- use depths

            nfdir = '/u/gens/nieto/stoch'
            ncfn=nfdir + '/stoch_' + length + 'km_' + time + 'h_' + depth + 'm_010T_002S_00U/ncom3d.nc'
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer and close the question please :)

Answer (score 1):

Reusing a variable name for a loop variable is a bad idea because it will persist after the loop exits. Consider, the following example:

```
outer_values = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
inner_values = ['12', '34', '56']

for outer_values in outer_values:
    print('outer: ' + repr(outer_values))
    for inner_values in inner_values:
        print('inner: ' + repr(inner_values))

# outer: 'ab'
# inner: '12'
# inner: '34'
# inner: '56'
# outer: 'cd'
# inner: '5'
# inner: '6'
# outer: 'ef'
# inner: '6'
```

On the second pass through, the name `inner_values` is still bound to the last string that was iterated over in the original `inner_values`, that is `'56'`. On the third pass through,  `inner_values` in then only bound to `'6'`.